# Wireless Access Points with API

Tags: wifi

I'm looking for an industrial grade (din mount, preferably weatherproof enclosure, no reboot every month like home APs, etc) Access Point / Bridge (802.11 b/g, dual radio) with **APIs**.

The issue here is **APIs**. Let me explain. I have built a management system that manages elements in the network and I want to support Wireless Access points. So are there any APs that have Web 2.0 style APIs (REST, Web Services, etc) or at least SSH with config files that I can download, modify and reboot AP?

Note that I can choose any AP for this solution as long as the requirements I've mentioned are met.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you look at the offerings from Ubiquiti (http://www.ubnt.com). They're a manufacturer of WISP-grade 802.11a/b/g APs. All their APs are Linux-based, and a development kit including toolchain is available. Out of the box you have SSH-based access to the OS running on the AP, but you could compile anything you want.

Comment: I saw "bullet" and it did not have DIN mount. I'll take a look at them again.

Comment: You're gonna have to help me w/ the term "DIN mount". That's outside my experience.

Answer (score 2):

if http interface is not strong requirement - take a look at [mikrotik](http://www.mikrotik.com/), i had reasonably good experience with it on router-board platforms. they are configurable over ssh / telnet.

btw - isn't it enough to use radius and put unauthenticated clients to separate vlan with captive portal? all additional things [ firewalling / bandwidth shaping ] could be sorted out on central router.

Comment: I'll take a look at MikroTik. I'm more interesting in changing SSID/Passkey than authenticating clients.

Comment: They're also configurable via an API, to there's no need to mess around with a SSH interpretation layer.

Answer (score 1):

Cisco has Cisco Cloud Connect, see [API and SDK info](https://developer.cisco.com/c/journal/view_article_content?groupId=5908138&articleId=5910487&version=3.2)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need. You could always get any supported WAP and install **dd-wrt** or similar OS on it. That will give you a whole bunch of services and configuration options including SSH. I regularly update the `/etc/hosts` file on my WAP with local entries and get the built-in DNS server to use it. Uptime is excellent too (run it for months without a reboot even on consumer WAP).

Comment: I agree. Probably the best way to do it. I think most problems with consumer grade APs are software and something like OpenWRT would work well.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco LWAPP seems to becoming or at least be the base of a new standard called [Capwap](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ohara-capwap-lwapp-04) for controlling thin access points. In turn, the controller ([WLC](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6366/products_qanda_item09186a008064a991.shtml)) doing this should have plenty of programatically accessible interfaces and of course ssh shell access as a last resort.

When deploying more than a few access points I'd always recommend a central controller solution and supporting those might be much easier than supporting actual individual access points - which may be thought more of as just dumb antennas.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately I don't want to have one more point of failure. Also Cisco controllers usually are very pricey.

Answer (score 0):

To shed some light for Evan Anderson, DIN 
is something like the NIST in the US, see

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_Institut_f%C3%BCr_Normung

I have used [LANCOM](http://www.lancom-systems.com) APs in such a situation. They are not that 
cheap, but very reliable
 and feature-rich. You can configure
them with http, ssh or a special software. I changed
 the WPA
passphrase via ssh every month, worked like charm.

Best regards.